# Can't create DNS TXT records with more than 255 characters on IBM Cloud

Tags: dns, ibm-cloud

On the IBM Cloud `DNS Services-dy`, I can't create certain `TXT` records. I get the error:

> JSON violates schema
>   Request JSON payload error: rdata.text in body should be at most 255 chars long
>   Trace ID: d48299c3-acc4-4e49-a7ef-583cbf6eea44

Of course there are very valid `TXT` records which surpass 255 characters. The same records I'm trying to create here worked on Google's `Cloud DNS` too. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is `DNS Services-dy`? I don't have access to IBM Cloud, but for TXT records a single string can't be longer than 255 characters, you can have multiple strings in a TXT record to get around this. Most DNS providers magically split up a long string into multiple strings of 255 chars or less.

Can you add multiple strings in an array or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

According to [rfc1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) (DOMAIN NAMES - IMPLEMENTATION AND SPECIFICATION), chapter 2.3.4. "Size limits":

```
Various objects and parameters in the DNS have size limits. [...] 
names           255 octets or less
```

Comment: But TXT records are list of such names, so you can have more than 255 bytes in total. Seee §3.3.14 in the exact RFC you quote: "TXT-DATA        One or more <character-string>s."

Comment: Yes. I think, there is possible to have several TXT-records inthe DNS. But, I assume, one record cannot be more than 255 (despite of RR-size is 16 bit word). Unfortunately, rfc1035 does not clearly explain, what is "name", and whose entities it spans.

Comment: "I think, there is possible to have several TXT-records inthe DNS. " This is true also but is separate. One TXT record is MULTIPLE character-strings, each one being 255 octets or less. RFC 1035 is clear for me on that point.

Comment: Basically you are confusing "name" and "character-string". As such your response is incorrect, as is the IBM Cloud service. TXT RDATA can be over 255 bytes long, but in those cases it has to be split in strings of at most 255 bytes (there is a confusion also between strings and bytes, we will consider US-ASCII only here for now), and one has to see which part of the system should do the split.